# Mockito/Spock MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mockito, spock

I am currently trying to use spock instead of junit in my unit tests.
But I ran into problem of `MissingMethodInvocationException`.

I am mocking `Provider<T>.get()`, like below

```
Provider<SomeOjb> a = Mock()
def setup(){
    SomeOjb obj = new SomeObj();
    Mockito.when(a.get()).thenReturn(obj)
}
```

but after running it I am getting

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException
when() requires as argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'
```

I tried two diffrent approach, one of them is to create mock as
`def a = Mock(Provider<SomeObj>)` but in this case I getting syntax error after running, issue is with `<>`

And the last idea was to just use annotation

```
@Mock
Provider<SomeObj> a;
```

and use when/then as before, and in this case it worked alright.
Any idea why firt idea is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I am stupid.
Issue was because I used Mockito api. Not spock mock api.

It should looks like:

```
Provider<SomeOjb> a = Mock()
def setup(){
    SomeOjb obj = new SomeObj();
    a.get() >> obj
}
```

Comment: You are certainly not stupid, you just made your own life harder than necessary by using Mockito even though Spock has its own built-in mock framework. That's just learning by doing. Even so, I recommend to read the excellent Spock manual before playing around with a tool you never used before. You will discover many cool features there, it is really worth your reading time and effort, I promise. 